# PHPStorm: How do I combine multiple Sass files into one?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I have _header.scss, _footer.scss and _main.scss and I want to combine them all into one and generate style.css.

I know it has to do with file watchers, but I haven't been able to figure out how to combine multiple files into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a PHPStorm feature, it's a SASS feature.

In style.scss it should start out with:

```
@import "_header";
@import "_footer";
@import "_main";
```

PHPStorm doesn't have to combine the files, Scss does.

Comment: you don't need underscore before the name of the file

Comment: The reason for using _ (underscore) is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889962/why-put-in-front-of-the-file-name-or-in-scss-css

Answer (score 2):

Create file styles.scss that contain this code

```
@import 'header';
@import 'main';
@import 'footer';
```

Answer (score 0):

[@SlawaEremkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3009562/slawa-eremkin) above is correct.

Be sure that the import file is named without an underscore (not a SASS partial) otherwise there won't be an output CSS file.

**Correct**

```
styles.scss
```

**Incorrect**

```
_styles.scss
```