# Why put in front of the file name "_" or "_" in scss/css?

Tags: css, import, sass

Why put `_` in front of the filename in scss?

`_filename.scss` -  Why does it need `_` ?

Comment: What's the difference between `"_"` and `"_"`?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

The _ (underscore) is a partial for scss. That means the stylesheet its going to be imported (@import) to a main stylesheet i.e. styles.scss. The advantage on using partials is that you can use many files to organize your code and everything will be compiled on a single file.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing out my mistake. "but `import '_file';` and `import 'file';` does the same thing right?"

Comment: If I structure my files in a way that I only ever send a single file to my compiler/preprocessor, why does it matter if my files are prepended with `_`? I'm considering removing the underscore from my file names. Whether or not a Sass file is a partial (i.e an importable piece of code) should depend on its location in your project's architecture, not how the file is named.

Comment: @ESR: Agreed, this feature feels a little outdated in a modern web dev environment. You definitely don't need the `_`s if you have your project structured in a reasonable way.

Comment: Why isn't `import '_file'` the preferred form? (Correct me if I'm wrong here, but it doesn't usually seem to be.) Since that is what the partial file *actually* is called. There might not even be a file called `file.scss`...

Comment: One important fact is missing, if you omit the underscore the import will still work, but for every scss file there will be a generated css file. Normally you don't want/need that and if they contain just mixins they usually will be 0 bytes long.

Comment: `@import` has been superseded by `@use`

Answer (score 92):

When you include "_" in front of the file name, it won't be generated into CSS unless you import it into another sass files which is not partial.

suppose your folder structure is like this

```
/scss
 style.scss
 _list.scss
/css
```

if you run the command

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

only style.css and style.css.map files will be created, sass compiler will omit _list.scss without converting its content into a CSS file.

```
/scss
 style.scss
 _list.scss
/css
 style.css
 style.css.map
```

the only way that you can use partials is to import them into another .scss file with

```
@import 'list.scss';
```

if you remove the '_' in front of _list.scss the outcome of the command will be

```
/scss
 style.scss
 list.scss
/css
 style.css
 style.css.map
 list.css
 list.css.map
```

The main purpose of using partials is to break down our CSS code into several pieces which are easier to maintain. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: This is the right answer. But, you also didn't mention the special case of _index.scss:  https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#index-files

Answer (score 76):

A sass file starting with an underscore is a partial. It is a good way to keep your styles separated into logical sections. These files all get merged on compilation when you use `@import`.

From the Sass language guide:

> You can create partial Sass files that contain little snippets of CSS that you can include in other Sass files. This is a great way to modularize your CSS and help keep things easier to maintain. A partial is simply a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the @import directive.

http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 17):

Files with _ (underscore) are ignored by compiler. However, all those files are imported into single, main SCSS file (i.e. styles.scss) which is actually the file that is compiled (it doesn't have _ (underscore) in it's name)

The final goal is to compile only one SCSS file, and to have only one CSS file as a result of that, which has various advantages.

Comment: If your using a system like webpack where it bundles and minifies your entire css it doesn't seem like you really need to use partials. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is what the documentation says](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#partials):

> As a convention, **Sass files that are only meant to be loaded as modules [to be imported], not compiled on their own, begin with _ (as in _code.scss).** These are called partials, and they tell Sass tools not to try to compile those files on their own. You can leave off the _ when importing a partial.

Also, note that [Sass partials should not be used with @import, but with @use instead](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import):

> The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the @use rule instead.  (Note that only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other implementations must use the @import rule instead.)

This is beyond the scope of the original question, but in case you're curious, here is why:

> The @import rule has a number of serious issues:
>
> - @import makes all variables, mixins, and functions globally accessible. This makes it very difficult for people (or tools) to tell where anything is defined.
> - Because everything’s global, libraries must prefix to all their members to avoid naming collisions.
> - @extend rules are also global, which makes it difficult to predict which style rules will be extended.
> - Each stylesheet is executed and its CSS emitted every time it’s @imported, which increases compilation time and produces bloated output.
> - There was no way to define private members or placeholder selectors that were inaccessible to downstream stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

_ is used to denote partials. These partials contains the variables and internal functions that are required in the pre-processing stage, and they are not required to be compiled as css. _ partial templates contains utils, scss local variables and functions required in the compilation of the scss to css.

Comment: This does not seem to add anything to the existing answers from years prior.

Answer (score -1):

Also using the watcher of node-sass in a node environment will result in error messages if you do without the underscore prefix, see https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2762