# Carry Sass variables across all stylesheet files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stylesheet

I have a **site_settings.scss** file which contain all the the variables for my Rails app:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/site_settings.scss

$primary_color: #4285F4;
$dark_color: #333333; 
...
```

Right now, if I want to use these variable inside a file i need to do this inside that file:

```
import 'site_settings.scss'
```

I need to put this at the beginning of **EVERY FILE** that I want to use these variables, otherwise Rails will give me the `Undefined variable:` error.

I have tried putting `import 'site_settings.scss'` inside the **application.scss** or **custom.scss** but neither of them is working.

I have also tried to use `require 'site_settings'` in the **aplication.scss** and rename application.scss to **application.css.scss** as being mentioned here: http://mildlyinternet.com/code/scss-variables-asset-pipeline.html , but it's still not working.

**Here is my application.scss:**

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome 
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
@import "devise";
@import "site_settings";
```

So, how do I solve this, so that I don't have to write `import 'site_settings.scss'` in every file each time?

Comment: Can you post the contents of application.css?

Comment: @PatrickO'Grady i have added it on the post

Comment: Have you tried to set it up exactly like in the linked article? Where you have `application.css`, with one `*= require file_name` statement, and then `file_name.scss` with all the imports?

Comment: @PatrickO'Grady yes, that's why i am posting here because that didn't work

Comment: @PatrickO'Grady if you want to look at the files, you can go here on github: https://github.com/ryzalyusoff/Quickrails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rename all files that will use the shared variables to start with `_`.
This will render the other files in context of partial files, which will use the previous declared variables in `@import 'site_settings'`. So you will have `site_settings.scss` and `quickrails/_general.scss`, `quickrails/_media_query.scss` and so on.

Those imports are considered partials, that is why the name should start with underscore, but when importing you use without it. Here is a material about this:

[Why put in front of the file name "_" or "_" in scss/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889962/why-put-in-front-of-the-file-name-or-in-scss-css)

Answer (score -1):

Replace any relevant `= require` with `@import` and remove any `= require` even if you think you've commented it out.