# Merge multiple scss files into one css file

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I'd like to merge all of my `scss` files into one compressed `css` file:

Structure:

- stylesheets/
- - test.scss
- - test2.scss
- gulpfile.js

I tried this two tasks, which I found in several answers and tutorials, but I always got the `scss` file into a duplicated `css` file:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('stylesheets/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
});
```

and

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('stylesheets/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css/styles.css'))
});
```

**!!! EFFECTIV RESULT !!!**

- stylesheets/
- - test.scss
- - test2.scss
- css/
- - test.css
- - test2.css
- gulpfile.js

**or with second tried task:**

- stylesheets/
- - test.scss
- - test2.scss
- css/styles.css/
- - test.css
- - test2.css
- gulpfile.js

**??? EXPECTED RESULT ???**

- stylesheets/
- - test.scss
- - test2.scss
- css/
- - styles.css
- gulpfile.js

Any ideas?

Comment: You just need to add a concat(styles.css)  call after the sass().  Look at gulp-concat.

Comment: @Mark Works, thanks! Can you please make an example for the others, so I can mark it as correct. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I'll make an example in a few hours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You indicated that you want to merge your files into one file and compress that file, so you need to add two plugins to do each of those.

[Gulp-concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat) and [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify)

```
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('stylesheets/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
  .pipe(uglify())

  // .pipe(rename({
   //  basename: "styles",
   //   suffix: ".min",
   //   extname: ".css"
  //  }))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});
```

In addition, you may want to add [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to indicate that the file has been uglified/minified via a .min.css extension (and change your html link to point to that filename).

Comment: Although concat will work I believe the OP should first consider using sass partials. It is very simple and keeps the code well organized. Concat might be good for logically separated stylesheets. 
Here's a quick explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890015 
So in stylesheets folder use single scss file to import modules with import rules for example @import "components/cards"; and then create modules beginning with underscore  (e.g. stylesheets/components/_cards.scss). Gulp will compile all into single file without any additional configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this hepls.

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  gulp.src([path.src.sass])
    .pipe(sassGlob())
    .on('error', util.log)
    .pipe(sass({
       includePaths: ['src/scss'],
    }))
    .on('error', util.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
});
```