# SASS variables do not work when only imported into a master file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have a partial sass file which holds mixins that I would like to access globally. My understanding is that all you need to do is @import this file into a master.scss file and it should be accessible globally. Sadly this isn't the case for me. I need to import the variable file into every individual .scss file I want to use it in. What do I nee to do to get so that importing it to the master.scss file I can access my mixins globally?

This is a rails app with my master.scss file imported into the application.scss file.

My assets tree

```
- scss
 -- utilities 
   -- _mixins.scss
 -- components
   -- buttons.scss
 master.scss
```

Contents of my master.scss file

```
@import 'utilities/_mixins';
@import 'components/buttons';
```

Contents of my mixins.scss file

```
@mixin square-size($size) {
  height: $size;
  width: $size;
}
```

Example of how I'm using the mixin in components/buttons.scss:

```
  .square-button {
    @include square-size(40px);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is it just silently 'not working'?

Comment: Yes, I get an "Undefined mixin" browser error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure it will resolve your problem but at least your code is cleaner this way.

Rename your `button.scss` to `_button.scss` and you don't need the write the underscore in `@import 'utilities/mixins';`

The underscore means the scss file is a partial. More info here: [Why put in front of the file name "_" or "_" in scss/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889962/why-put-in-front-of-the-file-name-or-in-scss-css)

Comment: That's a good catch. After "answering" my own question I spent some more time optimizing my file structure like you mentioned. It is cleaner, like you said, but files that utilize a mixin or extend still need to have the source file for these includes to be referenced at the top of the file. For some reason importing to a master file doesn't work. It's very frustrating. I've been looking for release notes for sass versions without luck. I wonder if this is the source of my problem? Perhaps I'm on an older version that doesn't support this flow?

Comment: How to you compile your sass code ? Maybe it's due to the compiler ?