# Separating SCSS and CSS files

Tags: css, sass

**This is my website folder structure:**

```
/images
/fonts
/js
/styles /    
        scss/
            |
            |– utilities/
            |   |– variables.scss  
            |
            |– base/
            |   |– reset.scss       
            |   |– typo.scss        
            |
            |– pages/
            |   |– index.scss       
            |   |– page1.scss            
            |
            – main.scss            

        css/ 
            // Save CSS Here

index.html
```

#### Description:

I have a `root` folder, contains `index.html` and few folders, like `fonts`, `js`, `styles`...
In the `styles` folder, there's two folder, `scss` and `css`. and in the `scss` folder, there's `main.scss` (which contains all the `scss` -imported-), and few folders with `scss` files, like: `base`, `utilities`, `pages`...

#### The Problem:

When I create a `scss` files the `compiler` creates the `css` and `css.map` in the **same** folder of the `scss` file that been created.
For example, after creating `variables.scss` it'll look like this:

```
|– utilities/
            |   |– variables.css   
            |   |– variables.css.map   
            |   |– variables.scss
```

#### The Question:

I'd like to have the CSS files saved in new folders *(Same for Sass but in the CSS folder)*. How can I separate the *two* types of files in different folders to look exactly like the example below?

#### What I'm Trying To Achieve:

```
/images
/fonts
/js
/styles /    
        scss/
            |
            |– utilities/
            |   |– variables.scss  
            |
            |– base/
            |   |– reset.scss       
            |   |– typo.scss        
            |
            |– pages/
            |   |– index.scss       
            |   |– page1.scss            
            |
            – main.scss            

        css/ 
            |
            |– utilities/
            |   |– variables.css
            |
            |– base/
            |   |– reset.css
            |   |– typo.css
            |
            |– pages/
            |   |– index.css
            |   |– page1.css
            |
            – main.css

index.html
```

#### EDIT (Note):

Using `LiveSassCompiler` to change the generated file location and using the `_` when naming the files to prevent generating all the files doesn't help. I need both folders and the nested files (generated CSS files). Check the **What I'm Trying to Achieve** example above.

Comment: It's really going to depend on your Sass Compiler. Check out this GitHub thread [here](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/84#issuecomment-411841424) for VSCode LiveSassCompiler

Comment: Also, for include-only `.scss` docs, consider adding an underscore before the filename to prevent it being compiled on it's own instead of as part of the main `.css` doc. (`_variables.scss` instead of `variables.scss`). Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889962/why-put-in-front-of-the-file-name-or-in-scss-css) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

i suggest using live sass compiler for transpiling scss files
for trying this :
go to

> menu- file>preferences>settings>extension>live sass copile config>edit in settings.json

and paste this:
(your save path can be customized)

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
{
  "format": "expanded",
  "extensionName": ".css",
  "savePath": "./css/"
}
```

]

Comment: I'd like to have the CSS files saved in new folders as in the example above. (Same for Sass but in the CSS folder)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the files you don't want to generate a CSS to have a underscore `"_"` before the name. And don't worry you don't need to change the name in the imports, SASS do that to you.

So your variables file would be `_variables.scss`

Comment: I know, adding "_" underscore won't generate new files, BUT I need the CSS files saved in new folders as in the example above. (Same for Sass but in the CSS folder)

Comment: Sorry then, I misunderstood the question. In this case depends on the compiler, with node Gulp and Ruby that is default behaviour, which compiler are you using?